# Trigger animations after full page load

Tags: jquery, html, css, dreamweaver

I'm creating a parallax website, and as you may all know it can get quite cluttered and junky. When loading up my page, some images take longer to load than others and therefore some animations are triggered before the entire page can load. I want the entirety of the page to load first and then have all animations ready. Anyway I can do this? I'm using jquery and scrollreveal.

Also, I don't know if this is worth mentioning but I've created a loading screen that disappears after the page has been fully loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `load` event on `window` to add a class to `body`, and base your CSS animations off of the class.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.classList.add('ready');
}
```

```css
img {
  transition: transform 5s;
}
.ready img {
  transform: rotate(5400deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.intrawallpaper.com/static/images/Golden-Gate-Bridge-HD-Wallpapers-WideScreen_FK1cfem.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
 //  Code here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // Code here
});
```

It triggers when everything is loaded.